# Connect to MYSQL server hosted on VMWARE ERROR 10061

Tags: mysql, database, networking, vmware

[Solved by changing NAT to Bridge suggested by Client]

I have install an configured MYSQL server on a VM(win7 32 bit). It runs locally fine but when I try to connect to my machin(host on which VM is running) I get 'Can't connect to mysql server on 192.168.1.99 (10061)'. Need a solution plz.

**Things that I have tried and not working:**

1. Disable firewall of VM
2. Reconfigure install
3. Check user previledge and FLUSH it.

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
4. Already read post related to solve this error but nothing works.

**IP Configuration:**

HOST   : 192.168.1.3

VM     : 192.168.1.90

VM NAT : 10.0.2.15

**Configuration of VM:**
Win 7 32bit without firewall, MYSQL 5.7 hosting on port 33061

**Configuration of Host:**
Win 7 64bit with firewall, MYSQL 8 hosting on 3306

**Configuration of MYSQL of VM:**
my.ini

```
[client]

# pipe=
# socket=MYSQL
port=33061
[mysql]
no-beep=

[mysqld]
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=33061
# socket=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/mysql.sock
# bind-address=0.0.0.0
# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
# basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/"
# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data
default-storage-engine=INNODB
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
# General and Slow logging.
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="DEV1-PC.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="DEV1-PC-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
# Binary Logging.
# log-bin=

# Error Logging.
log-error="DEV1-PC.err"

# Server Id.
server-id=1

lower_case_table_names=1

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

max_connections=151

table_open_cache=2000

tmp_table_size=9M

thread_cache_size=10

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M

key_buffer_size=8M

read_buffer_size=0

read_rnd_buffer_size=0

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M

innodb_log_file_size=48M

innodb_thread_concurrency=8

innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_open_files=300

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

back_log=80

flush_time=0

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=4M

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=4161

sort_buffer_size=256K

table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_master_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the mysql website;

> The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on ' server ' (10061)
>   indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should
>   check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network
>   connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the
>   one configured on the server.

**Trouble shooting network issues**

If your VM is on the LAN in the same subnet as the rest of your LAN and you want to access it via the LAN is should be in VM NAT bridge.

i would say this looks like a network related issue, at the first instance you should check you can ping the VM via ip address from commandline and also remote desktop to it via IP. If that fails that is likely where your issue is.

if you have network access, check you can connect via command line to the mysql instance on the VM from VM

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

if that works try from the host or remote machine

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h IPADDRESS -P PORTNUMBER
```

Comment: I am able to ping 192.168.1.99, but not RDC as it is the same connection VM is running on. I can connect to command line in VM. the last option I tried gives me 10061 error...C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u aabb-p -h 192.168.1.99 - P 33061 Enter password: ****** ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.99' (10061)

Comment: the VM and the host and all the other VM's should have unique Ip addresses and assigned to their vertical NICs, you should be able to RDC from one to the other. you mentioned 192.168.1.99 is that the ip of the VM that mysql is running?

Comment: Yes 192.168.2.99 is the IP for VM.

Comment: it might be a vm NAT issue, its in a completely different range to host, also unless your trying to connect to the VM from the WAN you don't need NAT on at all.

Comment: Ok so should I try with a different network setting on VM like bridge? But I want to run in this setup so simulate a intranet.

Comment: if you want to put your VM on your LAN and access it via the LAN use bridge mode.

Comment: Yes it works!, but putting it in bridge may end up in IP conflict and may change the IP due to DHCP, but it does the job for now, Thanks :)